# How to group Similar DataTable Items and show in One Row with aggregation values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, datatable, c#-3.0

I have Data table values like bellow now  I want to group these values into One Row Based on the Second column Value  and  able to calculate totals  like bellow . Any idea can be shared .

Required Format Data like Bellow

1KT049014L1(F),L2(F),R1(F),R2(F) Ghoousunnisa (F) 9999999999 Nellore 2200 220 1980 APIEasyBus   Agent

Actual Data Format

1 KT049014 L1 Ghoousunnisa (F) 9999999999   Nellore 550 55  495 API EasyBus Agent

2 KT049014 L2 Ghoousunnisa (F) 9999999999   Nellore 550 55  495 API EasyBus Agent

3 KT049014 R1 Ghoousunnisa (F) 9999999999   Nellore 550 55  495 API EasyBus Agent

4 KT049014 R2 Ghoousunnisa (F) 9999999999   Nellore 550 55  495 API EasyBus Agent

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("C", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("D", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("E", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("F", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("G", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("H", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("I", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("J", typeof(decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("K", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("L", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("M", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "KT049014", "L1", "Ghoousunnisa", "(F)", "9999999999", "Nellore", 550, 55, 495, "API", "EasyBus", "Agent");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "KT049014", "L2", "Ghoousunnisa", "(F)", "9999999999", "Nellore", 550, 55, 495, "API", "EasyBus", "Agent");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "KT049014", "R1", "Ghoousunnisa", "(F)", "9999999999", "Nellore", 550, 55, 495, "API", "EasyBus", "Agent");
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "KT049014", "R2", "Ghoousunnisa", "(F)", "9999999999", "Nellore", 550, 55, 495, "API", "EasyBus", "Agent");

        var datas =
            dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(row => row[1])
            .Select((group, i) => new {A = i + 1, B = group.Key, Others = combine(dt.Columns, group)});
        var result = dt.Clone();
        foreach (var d in datas)
        {
            var row = result.Rows.Add(d.A, d.B);
            for (int i = 0; i < d.Others.Count(); i++)
                row[i + 2] = d.Others.ElementAt(i);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<object> combine(DataColumnCollection columns, IGrouping<object, DataRow> group)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (columns[i].DataType == typeof(string))
                yield return string.Join(",", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>(i)).Distinct());
            else
                yield return group.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>(i));
        }
    }
}
```

L1(F),L2(F),R1(F),R2(F) :

```
string.Join(",", group.Select(r=>string.Concat(r[2], r[4])))
```

Ghoousunnisa (F) 9999999999 Nellore APIEasyBus Agent:

(I don't know if they are always the same in the group)

```
string.Join(",", group.Select(r=>r.Field<string>("D")))
string.Join(",", group.Select(r=>.Field<string>("D")).Distinct())
group.Select(r=>r.Field<string>("D")).First()
```

2200 220 1980:

```
group.Sum(r=>r.Field<decimal>("I"))
```

Comment: solution for this http://ramakrishnapathuri.blogspot.in/2013/09/listview-with-group-headers.html